# how to install and run oVirt on ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, kvm-virtualization, ovirt

is there any good explanation about how to install and run oVirt on Ubuntu 14.04 server?

I know for this link

https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/how-to/guest-agent/install-the-guest-agent-in-ubuntu/

but I still can't run oVirt on my Ubuntu.

https : // domain.example.com/webadmin

https: // domain.example.com/UserPortal

Does anybody know where I can find good tutorial about how to install and run oVirt on Ubuntu server 14.04?